# A native crash was detected: Flutter Integration test in Firebase test lab

Tags: flutter, firebase-test-lab, flutter-integration-test

I'm getting frequent App crashing error, running Flutter android app integration tests on Firebase test lab:

```
     *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/redfin/redfin:11/RQ3A.211001.001/7641976:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'MP1.0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2024-03-21 00:21:22-0700
pid: 23236, tid: 8673, name: DartWorker  >>> com.indihood.avanti.rc <<<
uid: 10274
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0xb4000079927a2f40)'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000021e1  x2  0000000000000006  x3  000000782ab7a560
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000000000000028
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  0000007b341ba7c0  x10 ffffff80fffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 0000000000000020  x13 3034663261373239  x14 0000000000000039  x15 000000782ab7a0c2
    x16 0000007b34252c80  x17 0000007b34234320  x18 0000007810e2e000  x19 0000000000005ac4
    x20 00000000000021e1  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000000  x23 0000000000000000
    x24 b4000078d28d3168  x25 b4000079927a2f40  x26 000000782ab7c000  x27 0000007615756b50
    x28 0000000800000076  x29 000000782ab7a5e0
    lr  0000007b341e8148  sp  000000782ab7a540  pc  0000007b341e8178  pst 0000000000001000
```

This appears in Firebase test lab real device, but when running the same set on local, there are no issues. How to debug and fix these issue which appears on Firebase test lab?

Comment: Do you have a recent matrix-id for a failing test run? If you post the id to the Slack #test-lab [channel](https://firebase-community.slack.com/archives/C1MTSQ5QT) it can be investigated.
Also, does your app call `exit()`? (from some Googling, it could cause this.)

Comment: There was no `exit()` call as such. I will post the matrix-id when next time failure appears to slack channel.